# Doesn't work ssl and www

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I'm having a problem with the ssl when I write www.example.com in the address bar. The browser show this error: Your connection is not secure. 
When I write example.com everything is ok.

I want to do a redirect through htaccess, this is my file:

`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

This works without www but not with www.

> Solution: finally it was a problem of SSL provider. After hour and a half on the phone they told me that all I had to do was add an alternate name (SAN) to the certificate including www.example.com

Comment: that only affects things hitting YOUR server. if you're loading external resources from a CDN (images, css, js, etc...) and using absolute non-ssl urls, you'll get the same warning because you're mixing secure and insecure content.

Comment: Your problem is most likely you bought a SSL cert and they didn't include `www` in the cert. Most good CAs will give www and non www certs as one certificate for no extra charge. While some (greedy) ca's make you pay for a separate cert for www because it's technically a subdomain. You need a cert that also includes www.  Go back to your SSL provider.

Comment: It can be the problem becasuse I'm not loading external resources. I don't get the warning when I write example.com

Comment: Thank you Panama Jack, I'll check it with my SSL provider, but I thought that maybe I could do it through htacces

Answer (score 0):

`EDIT: I can't down vote my own answer (pity) but  Panama Jack is correct, your SSL cert apparently does not cover www and non-www domains, if it did, the following might be helpful.`

I've always done that like this...

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

However if your site uses full URLS for things like images, js or css files..

```
 <img scr="http://www.example.com/pic.gif" >
```

You will see the same warnings. Best to use relative links, like

```
 <img scr="./pic.gif" >
```

or, if you must, use full URLs with https

```
 <img scr="https://www.example.com/pic.gig" >
```

Comment: Non of this will actually make a difference if the cert is not valid for `www`. Relative links is irrelevant, because he's trying to load https with www. He can't without a valid cert with www, period. Your answer doesn't not help at all.

Comment: Well gee thanks. but since we don't know if the cert is wildcarded, I did my best.

Comment: My point was I believe its a cert issue. and if it was a wildcard, he wouldn't have this problem as all subdomains would be valid. He'd be wasting time trying work arounds that wont fix his issue. :)

Comment: Finally it was a problem of SSL provider. After hour and a half on the phone they told me that all I had to do was add an alternate name (SAN) to the certificate including www.example.com. Thank you for help